# Sybase Stored Procedure stopped working after the database defrag

Tags: stored-procedures, sybase

The stored Procedure was working before the DB defrag. After the successful defrag one of the stored procedure stopped working (very slow with out any output). The indexes are complete. The stored procedure is doing something wrong, just cant nail it down. All other Stored procedures are working fine. Any idea what would have gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try to generate statistics for tables used in the procedure

```
update statistics TableName
```

or on indexes

```
update index statistics TableName
update index statistics TableName IndexName
```

Comment: Hi Parado. This problem is back. I used the above statements but gives me error. for update statistics I get error position too large. For update index I get syntax error near index

Answer (score 0):

Furthermore you can see which statement in the SP is the problem from master..sysprocesses.

Find process running the SP -sysprocesses has id and dbid in it, and you can use object_name(id,dbid) to identify yours, then you'll see stmtnum and linenum.

Get a dba or someone with sa_role to run sp_showplan on the running spid - that'll show the query plan.

If you've changed no index or data volumes at all then the above answer must be right - statistics need updating.  If this is Sybase 15 you should normally do UPDATE INDEX statistics, or it's quite likely you'll get some bad query plans (if you're allowing MERGE JOINs and HASH JOINs.)

Comment: Abe, I used the above statements but gives me error. for update statistics I get error position too large. For update index I get syntax error near index